# The simple calculator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, console, calculator

I wrote the simple calculator in Ruby. This is my first program in this language. I've switched recently from Python to Ruby. What do you think about my work? Thanks

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

def read_number(prompt = 'Enter the number: ')
  loop do
    print prompt
    user_input = Float(gets.chomp)

    return Float(user_input)
  rescue ArgumentError
    puts 'Error: not a number.'
  end
end

loop do
  puts '*** Main menu ***'
  puts '1) Add'
  puts '2) Subtract'
  puts '3) Multiply'
  puts '4) Divide'
  puts '5) Quit'
  user_choice = read_number 'Your choice: '

  exit if user_choice == 5

  first = read_number
  last = read_number

  case user_choice
  when 1
    puts "The result is #{first + last}"
  when 2
    puts "The result is #{first - last}"
  when 3
    puts "The result is #{first * last}"
  when 4
    begin
      raise ZeroDivisionError if last.zero?

      puts "The result is #{first / last}"
    rescue ZeroDivisionError
      puts 'Error: cannot divide by zero.'
    end
  else
    puts 'Error: invalid choice.'
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Ruby, but throwing an exception based on a condition (`last.zero?`) and directly catching it seems weird. Why not use a simple branch condition instead?

Answer (score 1):

Indent the `when` cases. You use 2 spaces - good.

```
case user_choice
  when 1
    puts "The result is #{first + last}"
  when 2
     puts "The result is #{first - last}"
  # ...
```

---

Using `case ... else`  - very good. Always have a "none of the above" in every `case` statement. But "It will never happen" - hey! I write perfect code every time too!

Display the invalid entry to the user.

---

Be The User

Think about what a User *can* do, not what you *expect* or they *should* do.

Don't ask for the numbers after entering an invalid operation code. Users will interpret error messages in the context of what they just did. Prompting for numbers - operands - after entering, say, "8" for the operation seems like a bug. But then AFTER I enter numbers you tell me 'invalid choice'. What? You don't like the numbers I just entered? I know you mean the operator choice only because I read the code.

Show the user the invalid entry. Explain what is valid if necessary.

Keep the `case ... else`.  No, it is not redundant.

---

Validating Operator Code Entry

Do this before prompting for the operands.

You can test the entry is within a Range.  Read Ruby docs about `Range` objects. It make for nicely readable and concise code.

You can force the entry to an integer - `to_i`.  , but maybe not second-guessing the user is better and just re-prompt. You decide. But as a general rule when comparing numbers it is best if they are the same - integer - integer, float - float.

You might assume anything NOT 1 - 4 means quit. Sure, keep "5 - Quit".  Play around with it and see how it feels as a design feature of your app.

---

```
user_input = Float(gets.chomp)
return Float(user_input)    # isn't this redundant? In two ways?
```

I mean the `Float()` call. Also, the following will return the number if it is the last statement in the method.

```
Float(gets.chomp)  # explicit return not required
```

As a beginner keep using `return` explicity until you are comfortable with the idea that a method's last statement is what is returned with or without `return`.

Not using `return` is idiomatic. Ruby strives to be free of superfluous syntax and extranious verbiage.

---

Domain language

The domain is math. Use math-talk; "operator" and "operand". See below how that tells us what it is? Always write so the code reads as what it is about, i.e. its "domain."

```
# user_choice = read_number
operator = read_number 'Your choice: '

 # and ...

# first = read_number
# last  = read_number

first_operand = read_number
last_operand  = read_number

case operator
  # ...
  puts "The result is #{first_operand + last_operand}"
```